# Using Nodejs in amazon ec2 with sudo

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a node server on aws ec2. I installed node from source to the latest stable version. I have a file `program.js`. When I run this with `node program.js`, it creates a server and starts running. But I want to use port 443, so when I run `sudo node program.js` it gives the following error :

```
setInterval(()=>{
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
```

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

What is the problem?

Comment: Could you please share the whole code?

Comment: As the error suggests the issue is with syntax. It would be helpful if you provide your code snippet.

Comment: It's not a good idea (for security reasons) to run your app as root. If there was a vulnerability in your app it could give an attacker root access to your server. The standard way to have your app listen to ports 80 and 443 is to setup IP tables rules that forward traffic on those ports to whatever port your application is actually running on.